# can't start android studio after upgrading ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: android-studio, 17.10

Android studio was working fine. But after I upgrade ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 and then try to start android studio I got the following error .

```
sudo ./android-studio/bin/studio.sh 
[sudo] password for user: 
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
Start Failed: Internal Error. Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1043)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:454)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:311)
    at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:578)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1501)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1312)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.<init>(StyleContext.java:1259)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:107)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.<init>(StyleContext.java:87)
    at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:166)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet(HTMLEditorKit.java:391)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:102)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Comment: Try executing `xhost si:localuser:root` first

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks!!! what does this do though ?? and will I have to execute this every time ?

Comment: There is a feature(?) in wayland which prevents programs which need root access from operating GUI programs.  I've marked this to close, and referenced a pretty good answer about that.